# Get every href from the same div in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I have this soup:

[image]

The webpage has references of companies in a grid view (16 rows x 5 columns) and I want to retrieve each reference's url and the title. The problem is that all 5 references in each row, are in one class named `row` and when I'm scraping the page, I can only see the first reference of every row, instead of all 5 of them. Here is my code so far:

```
url = 'http://www.slimstock.com/nl/referenties/'

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

info_block = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "row"})

references = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company Name', 'Web Page'])

for entry in info_block:
    try:

        title = entry.find('img').get('title')
        url = entry.a['href']
        urlcontent = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

        row = [{'Company Name': title, 'Web Page': url}]
        references = references.append(row, ignore_index=True)  

    except:
        pass
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should iterate over the "img" or over the "a".
You can write something like this:

```
for entry in info_block:
try:
    for a in entry.find_all("a"):
        title = a.find('img').get('title')
        url = a.get('href')
        urlcontent = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
        row = [{'Company Name': title, 'Web Page': url}]
        references = references.append(row, ignore_index=True)  
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Can I ask you something extra, since I'm very new to this? At the page bottom there is a `Show more...` option, and if it was a button class I would just use Selenium and say `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=\"Show more...\"]")).click();`. But this is not the case. It is only in a `<a style>` element, that is inside a `<strong>` element, that is inside a `<p align>` element. How can I scrape it to automatically "click" the `Show more...`?Thanks in advance!

Comment: @joasa AFAIK, you cannot do this now since you are working on the static html page. You will have to "press the button" in some other way (for example, using selenium).

Comment: Ah ok, I will try to find a way with Selenium, although these `<strong>` and `<a style>` instances confuse me a lot. Thanks for the help, cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'http://www.slimstock.com/nl/referenties/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
info_block = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "row"})
references = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company Name', 'Web Page'])

for entry in info_block:
    anchors = entry.find_all("a")
    for a in anchors:
        try:
            title = a.find('img').get('title')
            url = a['href']
            # urlcontent = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
            row = [{'Company Name': title, 'Web Page': url}]
            references = references.append(row, ignore_index=True)

        except:
            pass
```